# My function is not called a second time why

Tags: php

Here is my code for my simple function, below when I use echo and my function with a number greater than zero, the function returns true(1), when the number is less than zero, nothing happens, the code and the output of the program are attached

```
<?php
  function isPositive(int $number) : bool{
        return $number > 0;
    }

    echo "test\n";
    echo isPositive(1);
    echo "test\n";
    echo isPositive(-1);
    echo "test\n";
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0MMn.png)

I expected the is Positive(-1) function to return false (0)

Comment: If you print boolean `false` you'll get an empty string -> https://3v4l.org/gV2KD#v8.2.2

Comment: as pointed out above when echoing the boolean, it will be type coerced to string as empty string. You may use `var_dump` to echo the variable as is